# XSL escape characters for a child nodes only

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to escape the characters of the child nodes and fields. I want to retain the `<`, `>` and `"` of other parent nodes. Is this possible via XSL? When I'm testing right now, all characters are escaped including the `<>"` of the parent nodes.

I got this code from StackOverflow two weeks before careof Chris Scott.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge"><ns0:Message1>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
</ns0:Message1></ns0:Messages>
    </xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&#32;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">=&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ns0:Messages | ns0:Message1">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please see source sample below:

```
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
 <ns0:Message1>
  <Information>
   <Contact>
    <Name type="Data">
     <FirstName>John</FirstName>
     <LastName>Doe</LastName>
     <Title>Mr.</Title>
    </Name>
    <MobileNumber>0123456789</MobileNumber>
    <Email>johndoe@coldmail.com</Email>
    <Address>Antartica</Address>
   </Contact>
   <Contact>
    <Name type="Data">
     <FirstName>Mara</FirstName>
     <LastName>Sov</LastName>
     <Title>Queen</Title>
    </Name>
    <MobileNumber>9999999999</MobileNumber>
    <Email>marasov@reef.com</Email>
    <Address>Reef</Address>
   </Contact>
   <Department>HR</Department>
  </Information>
 <Information>
   <Contact>
    <Name type="Data">
     <FirstName>John</FirstName>
     <LastName>Doe</LastName>
     <Title>Mr.</Title>
    </Name>
    <MobileNumber>0123456789</MobileNumber>
    <Email>johndoe@coldmail.com</Email>
    <Address>Antartica</Address>
   </Contact>
   <Contact>
    <Name type="Data">
     <FirstName>Mara</FirstName>
     <LastName>Sov</LastName>
     <Title>Queen</Title>
    </Name>
    <MobileNumber>9999999999</MobileNumber>
    <Email>marasov@reef.com</Email>
    <Address>Reef</Address>
   </Contact>
   <Department>HR</Department>
  </Information>
</ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Please see target sample below:

```
<ns0:Messages>
 <ns0:Message1>
  <Information>
   &lt;Contact&gt;
    &lt;Name type=&quot;Data&quot;&gt;
     &lt;FirstName>John&lt;/FirstName&gt;
     &lt;LastName>Doe&lt;/LastName>
     &lt;Title>Mr.&lt;/Title&gt;
    &lt;/Name&gt;
    &lt;MobileNumber&gt;0123456789&lt;/MobileNumber&gt;
    &lt;Email&gt;johndoe@coldmail.com&lt;/Email&gt;
    &lt;Address&gt;Antartica&lt;/Address&gt;
   &lt;/Contact&gt;
  &lt;Contact&gt;
    &lt;Name type=&quot;Data&quot;&gt;
     &lt;FirstName>Mara&lt;/FirstName&gt;
     &lt;LastName>Sov&lt;/LastName>
     &lt;Title>Queen&lt;/Title&gt;
    &lt;/Name&gt;
    &lt;MobileNumber&gt;9999999999&lt;/MobileNumber&gt;
    &lt;Email&gt;marasov@reef.com&lt;/Email&gt;
    &lt;Address&gt;Reef&lt;/Address&gt;
   &lt;/Contact&gt;
   <Department>HR</Department>
  </Information>
  <Information>
   &lt;Contact&gt;
    &lt;Name type=&quot;Data&quot;&gt;
     &lt;FirstName>John&lt;/FirstName&gt;
     &lt;LastName>Doe&lt;/LastName>
     &lt;Title>Mr.&lt;/Title&gt;
    &lt;/Name&gt;
    &lt;MobileNumber&gt;0123456789&lt;/MobileNumber&gt;
    &lt;Email&gt;johndoe@coldmail.com&lt;/Email&gt;
    &lt;Address&gt;Antartica&lt;/Address&gt;
   &lt;/Contact&gt;
  &lt;Contact&gt;
    &lt;Name type=&quot;Data&quot;&gt;
     &lt;FirstName>Mara&lt;/FirstName&gt;
     &lt;LastName>Sov&lt;/LastName>
     &lt;Title>Queen&lt;/Title&gt;
    &lt;/Name&gt;
    &lt;MobileNumber&gt;9999999999&lt;/MobileNumber&gt;
    &lt;Email&gt;marasov@reef.com&lt;/Email&gt;
    &lt;Address&gt;Reef&lt;/Address&gt;
   &lt;/Contact&gt;
   <Department>HR</Department>
  </Information>
 </ns0:Messages>
</ns0:Message1>
```

Currently, the output in my XSL mapping is not quite what I'm expecting.

```
   <ns0:Messages>
     <ns0:Message1>
      &lt;Information&gt;
       &lt;Contact&gt;
        &lt;Name type=&quot;Data&quot;&gt;
         &lt;FirstName>John&lt;/FirstName&gt;
         &lt;LastName>Doe&lt;/LastName>
         &lt;Title>Mr.&lt;/Title&gt;
        &lt;/Name&gt;
        &lt;MobileNumber&gt;0123456789&lt;/MobileNumber&gt;
        &lt;Email&gt;johndoe@coldmail.com&lt;/Email&gt;
        &lt;Address&gt;Antartica&lt;/Address&gt;
       &lt;/Contact&gt;
      &lt;Contact&gt;
        &lt;Name type=&quot;Data&quot;&gt;
         &lt;FirstName>Mara&lt;/FirstName&gt;
         &lt;LastName>Sov&lt;/LastName>
         &lt;Title>Queen&lt;/Title&gt;
        &lt;/Name&gt;
        &lt;MobileNumber&gt;9999999999&lt;/MobileNumber&gt;
        &lt;Email&gt;marasov@reef.com&lt;/Email&gt;
        &lt;Address&gt;Reef&lt;/Address&gt;
       &lt;/Contact&gt;
       &lt;Department&gt;HR&lt;/Department&gt;
      &lt;/Information&gt;
      &lt;Information&gt;
       &lt;Contact&gt;
        &lt;Name type=&quot;Data&quot;&gt;
         &lt;FirstName>John&lt;/FirstName&gt;
         &lt;LastName>Doe&lt;/LastName>
         &lt;Title>Mr.&lt;/Title&gt;
        &lt;/Name&gt;
        &lt;MobileNumber&gt;0123456789&lt;/MobileNumber&gt;
        &lt;Email&gt;johndoe@coldmail.com&lt;/Email&gt;
        &lt;Address&gt;Antartica&lt;/Address&gt;
       &lt;/Contact&gt;
      &lt;Contact&gt;
        &lt;Name type=&quot;Data&quot;&gt;
         &lt;FirstName>Mara&lt;/FirstName&gt;
         &lt;LastName>Sov&lt;/LastName>
         &lt;Title>Queen&lt;/Title&gt;
        &lt;/Name&gt;
        &lt;MobileNumber&gt;9999999999&lt;/MobileNumber&gt;
        &lt;Email&gt;marasov@reef.com&lt;/Email&gt;
        &lt;Address&gt;Reef&lt;/Address&gt;
       &lt;/Contact&gt;
       &lt;Department&gt;HR&lt;/Department&gt;
      &lt;/Information&gt;
     </ns0:Messages>
    </ns0:Message1>
```

Both the `Information` node and its child node `Department` are being escaped as well. I need only the `Contact` segment with all its child nodes to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a corrected version of your stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">


  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&#32;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">=&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Messages | ns0:Message1 |Information | Department">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template `<xsl:template match="text()">` wasn't useful so that it has been removed.

This is what I obtain so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
 <ns0:Message1>
  <Information>
   &lt;Contact&gt;
    &lt;Name type=&quot;Data&quot;&gt;
     &lt;FirstName&gt;John&lt;/FirstName&gt;
     &lt;LastName&gt;Doe&lt;/LastName&gt;
     &lt;Title&gt;Mr.&lt;/Title&gt;
    &lt;/Name&gt;
    &lt;MobileNumber&gt;0123456789&lt;/MobileNumber&gt;
    &lt;Email&gt;johndoe@coldmail.com&lt;/Email&gt;
    &lt;Address&gt;Antartica&lt;/Address&gt;
   &lt;/Contact&gt;
   &lt;Contact&gt;
    &lt;Name type=&quot;Data&quot;&gt;
     &lt;FirstName&gt;Mara&lt;/FirstName&gt;
     &lt;LastName&gt;Sov&lt;/LastName&gt;
     &lt;Title&gt;Queen&lt;/Title&gt;
    &lt;/Name&gt;
    &lt;MobileNumber&gt;9999999999&lt;/MobileNumber&gt;
    &lt;Email&gt;marasov@reef.com&lt;/Email&gt;
    &lt;Address&gt;Reef&lt;/Address&gt;
   &lt;/Contact&gt;
   <Department>HR</Department>
  </Information>
  <!-- More elements ... -->
 </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

You can see it work here: http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQeV

Comment: let me test this sir potame

Comment: hi sir potame! I think it worked, can I add just one more node? I failed to notice it, I apologize.

Comment: There's a child node inside Information and the parent node of Contact which is <Details>. Details is in the same level with Department and it should be <Details> in the output as well. not escaped

Comment: Then you can add the `<Details>` tag in the list of matching elements of the template `<xsl:template match="ns0:Messages | ns0:Message1 |Information | Department">`